# Implementation of SQL "LIKE" Operator in Database Outsourcing

Tags: encryption, databases, outsourcing, string

Recently, I read some papers about `DB Outsourcing` that implement aggregate functions over encrypted data. What I want to know, is there a method in `DB Outsourcing` to implement `SQL LIKE` operator that supports the queries include this for encrypted data? (I found [CryptDB](http://CryptDB:%20A%20Practical%20Encrypted%20Relational%20DBMS%20-%20people.csail.mit.edu) and [IntegriDB](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~zhangyp/papers/IntegriDB.pdf) for this, but they don't describe their method).

Comment: What do you mean "DB outsourcing?"  Do you simply mean that the database server is run by a third party?

Comment: Simply, DB Outsourcing means that you use an external company to manage your database operations.@JohnWu

Comment: OK.  I think you are asking "Is there a database platform that will prevent administrators or anyone else with access to the server from seeing any of the data, yet will allow query functionality including the LIKE operator?"  Is that right?

Comment: Somewhat yes, for more information visit this: http://sprout.ics.uci.edu/past_projects/odb/ @JohnWu